# How to trigger a Maximo Workflow from a Web-service call

Tags: workflow, maximo

Hi is there any way to route a Maximo workflow process instance of a given obect using an external web-service call?

Could find documentation to initialize and wake up workflows, but not to route them.

To clarify I´d like to be able to perform the same kind of action as the"Route Workflow" of Maximo interface on an external system

I´m running on Maximo 7.6.0.3

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For whom it may concern

After a while got it working using automation scripts and using a small customization on the UserDetail.class (to allow changing personid via automtionscripts).

Comment: could you enhance this answer with a piece of the script and some details about the configuration (ea: launchpoints, integration setup etc.)